# Write a method that finds the product of all positive entries, while ignoring negative entries

Tags: java

We have to write a method that is called from a menu that will find the product of a collection of entered data values. The program should ignore all negative values and terminate when a zero value is encountered. We have some code written, but it is not functioning the way it should. We've gotten it to where it will ignore the negative numbers, but will not calculate and display the product correctly.

```
public void prodNoNegative () throws IOException
{
    float input = 0;
    float temp = 0;
    String s;

    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Enter a string of numbers followed by 0 to exit");

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String line = br.readLine();

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
    input = Float.parseFloat(st.nextToken());

    if (input==0) {
        System.out.print("END");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    while (input !=0) {
        if (input<0) {
            System.out.println (input + " is ignored.");
        } else if (input>0);
        {
            temp = input * temp;
        }

        input = Float.parseFloat(st.nextToken());
    }

    s = Float.toString(temp);

    System.out.println("The product of all positive inputs is " +s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You initialize `temp` to 0, so no matter what you multiply, it's still going to be 0. You should initialize `temp` to 1.

Also, you have an extra semicolon here:

```
else if (input>0);
{
    temp = input * temp;
}
```

Remove it, because it is interpreted as an empty statement, and so the next lines execute regardless of the `else if`.

2nd edit:

You could add a flag boolean initially set to false and assign it true in the line after `temp = input * temp`. If all the input values were negative, then the boolean would never be set to true. Then you can check the boolean when printing your the result.

Like so:

```
...
boolean flag = false;
...
else if (input>0);
{
    temp = input * temp;
    flag = true;
}
...
if (flag) System.out.println("The product of all positive inputs is " + s);
else System.out.println("You didn't enter any positive numbers.");
```

Comment: I changed temp to 1. It works now if I enter all positive numbers, however, if I enter all negative numbers, it states that the negative numbers are ignored, but still performs the equation.

Comment: Ok, great! We're really close, but one issue still. When we input ALL negative numbers it gives us a product of 1. I think it should be either no output at all, or an output of 0. Right? Do we need to add something?